# 15.04 - Can only hear sound through speakers if headphones are unplugged

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

Linux Newbie here...

My motherboard is an MSI 870A-G54.

Headphones and mic are plugged through the front of my case, speakers are plugged in the back straight into the line out jack.

In the sound settings I see both options for headphones and Line Out.

I would like to be able to switch from one to the other when both are plugged in.

When "Headphones" is selected, I hear fine through the headphones.  if I select "Line Out" the headphones are muted, but no sound comes out of the speakers.

If I unplug the headphones, and Line Out is selected, sound comes out of the speakers.

I tried a few things with alsamixer and pulseaudio, but to no avail.  These are currently installed.

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.